# I want to declare a property name as Line#

Tags: c#, json

I have a Json data returning from service which contains field like Line# and others
I am creating Model class which  will have property names same as the these filed. I will map the Json data and model class since the field name are same it will automatically map the values.

problem what i am facing is i cannot declare property name as Line# [against coding guidelines gives error]
Is there any alternative way for this?

Comment: can you provide sample code?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) (and if you're not, you should probably look into it), you can specify the serialized member name with the `JsonProperty` attribute:

```
[JsonProperty("Line#")]
public int LineNumber { get; set; }
```

If you're using the built-in [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), specify the name in the `DataMember` attribute:

```
[DataMember(Name = "Line#")]
public int LineNumber { get; set; }
```

Comment: what if not using JSON.Net? :-)

Comment: @Grundy I've provided a solution for the `DataContractJsonSerializer` as well.